# Cannot start windows

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I tried to install Ubuntu 12.10 LTS and I had made a partition in Windows, and I booted from a live CD and tried to install on that partition. The installation didn't work, so I checked the file, and there is a file missing from the .iso. Now I am unable to boot from Windows and I am running off a slow live session. Please help me!!
P.S When I try to boot windows, it stays on the splash screen trying to boot, and there isn't a way to access the recovery partition. I don't have windows discs either.

Comment: 12.04 is LTS, 12.10 is not.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, such problems occur when you use re-writable cds. Obtain a live CD that is able to install ubuntu properly. Then install it on the partition that doesn't have any windows data. The installation should also install the grub, which will allow you to boot into either of your operating systems.

Even if you are not able to recover windows, you should be able to recover your files.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I have also tried this on a USB stick and it fails

Comment: make sure your system meets minimum requirements for ubuntu 12.04 what was the size of the partition you created for ubuntu, size of the usb.
p.s. i think the reason widows isn't starting is because you created the partition from windows, while in windows, and divided the partition that had windows on it.

Comment: Ok, so I did partition in Windows, and made a 30 GB partition. The USB size is 4gb, I have 2GB of ram, AMD Vision E300.

Comment: I just want to know how to make a new partition from my main drive through the Ubuntu installer.

Answer (score 0):

First, download the iso image again, [check the MD5 or SHA checksum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) (to ensure that the downloaded iso is correct byte-per-byte), finally burn it at a slow speed (to reduce the likelihood of a write error).

The partition that Windows created is probably FAT or NTFS, and Ubuntu cannot be installed on either of them. In the Live CD, open Gparted, delete the partition you created in Windows. Then run the installer, choose "Install alongside Windows", and leave the partitioning work to the installer.

If the installation aborts, please tell us the exact error message.